# PowerShell output different between remote (invoke-command) and local commands

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2

I have looked though Stack Overflow for this question and haven't been able to find it. I also searched the internet with no luck so far. The answers I have found so far do not address the difference I am seeing in the same command being run from two different locations for the same server.  Maybe I am not using the correct search parameters.

My Problem:

PowerShell commands shows different output when using remote invoke-command as opposed to running the command locally. I have seen this on a couple occasions.

For this example, The server running the remote invoke command is running Windows Server 2012 with PS 4 version.

The server being tested is running Windows Server 2008 R2 with PS 2 version.

I log into both servers with the Domain Administrator login.

```
====
**Notice Version shows 1.0.0.0 when using remote command.

2012 v4:
```

(I tried piping to format table, but same result)

```
invoke-command -computername mail1.dcloud.cisco.com -scriptblock {Get-host} 

PSComputerName   : mail1.dcloud.cisco.com
RunspaceId       : 6ccceb7b-5fa0-42b7-b78f-22b17116f4d3
Name             : ServerRemoteHost
Version          : 1.0.0.0
InstanceId       : 28263e00-11f9-4d78-98c2-f789659b23c8
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : en-US
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : 

===========
** Notice version is 2.0 when run locally on server.

2008 R2 v2

PS C:\> $env:ComputerName
MAIL1

PS C:\> get-host


Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 2.0
InstanceId       : d4cf14b5-5925-4fb5-9307-eaf8cbcd11f5
UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : en-US
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost+ConsoleColorProxy
IsRunspacePushed : False
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.LocalRunspace
```

12/2/17 13:25 EDT - EDIT:
If I change my command to enter-pssession, I get the info that I believe to be correct.

```
PS C:\python> enter-pssession mail1
Get-host


Name             : Windows PowerShell ISE Host
Version          : 4.0
InstanceId       : 7e3f6039-3b63-4c8e-af49-bc748c07ed7e
UI               :System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
CurrentCulture   : en-US
CurrentUICulture : en-US
PrivateData      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Host.ISE.ISEOptions
IsRunspacePushed : True
Runspace         : System.Management.Automation.RemoteRunspace


[mail1]: PS C:\Users\Administrator.DCLOUD\Documents> exit-pssession
```

Still have not found out why `Invoke-Command` gives a different output for the command `Get-Host`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-Host` returns the details of the current host. If you are in PowerShell console, it returns the version of the console host. If you are in a remote session it returns the version of the remote host(not the PS version in remote server).

**Note: Host version and PowerShell version aren't same.**

even ISE is a different host for powershell

Comment: Thank you Prasoon Karunan for that answer. I did not know that. I will adjust my script accordingly.